# Google has disabled the use of the maps API for this application

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Today I was trying to add JQuery Mobile elements to a site which uses a google map when suddenly I started to get this message:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.

I reverted all the changes I had made thinking they might have somehow caused this but that didn't fix it. What's worse I am also getting the message on the live version of my site which has worked flawlessly for weeks and has not had anything changed on it in a few days.

I know my google maps script is done correctly as it has been working fine for a long time and the error message I am getting is different to the one that people get when they address their script incorrectly. My error message seems to be completely generic and provides no reason why it has stopped working.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikeygoeshere&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(Obvious I'm not using that as a key)

If I check my API Console it says no known issues for the API V3.

I have done all the usual checks like clearing browser cache, using different browsers, getting a new API key etc.

This is really annoying for me as my whole site is built around the map meaning I can't work on it at all with this problem.

Comment: The error message suggests that your application has been specifically blocked for some reason. **You will need to contact Google.**

Comment: Is there a proper way to contact them regarding this? I've looked through all the help pages on the google developers site and I can't find a contact address anywhere. All there seems to be is a feedback form which I don't think is supposed to be for support

Comment: Have you looked in the account where the key was generated from? https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: Yes and it reports the status as "No known issues"

Comment: same problem here, started 2-3hs ago.

Comment: That's good to hear hopefully it's an issue at their end then

Comment: Same problem here! please keep us updated if solution found :)

Comment: google issue. Take the time now to abstract your reliance so you can switch providers :)

Comment: Today we experienced a temporary outage on a number of sites using the Google Maps JavaScript API. We’re aware of the issue and have rolled out a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue here. Looks to be a google error as I doubt google would be violating their own terms of use.

http://www.google.com.au/about/jobs/locations/sydney/

Comment: Well that's pretty definitive! Hopefully it's fixed soon

Answer (score 10):

It looks like it is working if you don't specify an API key:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhSg6I2JvHNU_jLqIpvc5MEwc_xi3Ttvg&sensor=true"></script>
```

vs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

(Taken from http://www.google.com.au/about/jobs/locations/sydney/)

Comment: Cool that worked for me too. At least I can keep working on my local version until it's fixed now

Comment: this only allows a minimum number of requests. around 10 in total.

Comment: So what can i do, to communicate between my android app and google map v3? API KEY is necessary.